# HC-05 bluetooth module and android communication

Tags: module, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, rfcomm

I need to establish communication between android application and HC05 bluetooth module.I searched internet found about rfcomm based bluetooth communication. Is rfcomm based communication is the best method ? Can any one provide links for sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes RFCOMM is the way to connect to HC05 bluetooth modules. The HC05 bluetooth modules acts as a server waiting for connection like any standar bluetooth device. You just have to follow [android api guide for bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) to create an application to connect to the device and communicate with it.